# How draw decision boundry of 4 dimentional Iris data in libsvm?

Tags: matlab, classification, libsvm

I tried svm with 4 features. I used Libsvm for training classifier then I want to draw decision boundries. I tried to draw in 2D space in matlab for 1 vs 3 (One vs One) and the 2D features were columns 1 and 3 of Iris data but it drew the wrong decision boundry. What is wrong? What should I do?

```
coef1v3 = [model.sv_coef(1:7,2); model.sv_coef(27:45,1)];
SVs1v3 = [model.SVs(1:7,:); model.SVs(27:45,:)];
b=model.rho;
w1v3 = SVs1v3'*coef1v3;
b1v3=b(2);
xp=linspace(min (data(:,1)),max (data(:,1)));
yp1=(-w1v3(1)*xp+b1v3)/w1v3(3);
plot(xp , yp1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is wrong. just try dimension 1 and 3.No need to try every dimension.I did it and got true response.